# when I put 'console.log(err.message)' in error handler of express app, It keeps logging endlessly but why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I'm just trying to make basic error handling function which response with json data of error and logging on the console about the error.

But when I put `console.log(err.message);'` in the error handler and launch the server(by `npm install`, `npm start`). It keeps logging even if I'm not doing anything..

It seems to logging the message for `404("Not Found")` which I defined just before the error handler module.

It maybe just problem of my local setting but I don't know what it is. I'm using `Atom`

```
//for 404
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status=404;
  next(err);
});

//error handler
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(err.message);
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({error:{
    message:err.message
  }});
})
```

I expect the output must be nothing if I'm not doing anything. And only logging on the console with some wrong request.
[image]

and as recommended below, I added module for req.url and found there was infinite '/json/version' and '/json/ request... 
but where it coming from..? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cvhc.png)

Comment: Are you running some monitoring program that might be pinging your web server?

Comment: Add `console.log(req.url)` to `app.use`-middleware to get a problem url. P.S. I recommend to use next routes `/quotes/:id(\\d+)` and `/quotes/random`.

Comment: @jfriend00 No I think I'm not... how can I check any monitoring program is running?

Comment: @AikonMogwai   When I added that module right before 404 module, '/json/version' and '/json' are logged on the console alternatively.. what it means..?

Comment: That means that your browser send these requests :) Check your browser code.

Comment: @AikonMogwai   Oh.. yes it was the browser. I don't know why but when I shut down all the browser and re-start it, the endless loop is ended. Thank you very much!! but Do you know why it is?

Comment: Nope. It looks like your code. Maybe it was debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause using the morgan package. Morgan is a HTTP request logger package that you can use in express. https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan

I installed morgan using the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const app = express()

app.use(morgan('dev'))
```

When I executed your code I had the error logged to the console a number of times.

Here is the output:

[image: morgan logging results]

In my case the error logged twice because the browser requested the favicon.ico file (which doesn't exist in my project).

This is no big issue. But if it is occuring more that twice, install morgan and you will be able to log the requests and see what is causing the multiple error messages.